# Removing duplicate Unicode characters

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, extension-methods

#### Motivation

I came across an interesting question on SO: [determine-if-string-has-all-unique-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667415/determine-if-string-has-all-unique-characters) and thought about providing an extension method to enable duplicate removal given some kind of normalization.

#### Description

> The goals:
>
> - Remove any duplicate characters (keep the first occurence) and return the updated string.
> - The method should be able to handle *diacritics* and *extended unicode* characters.
> - The method should allow the consumer to control normalization to find duplicates (for instance, case-sensitivity).

#### Questions

- Looking for general feedback on C# conventions
- Performance feedback
- Am I reinventing the wheel?

#### Code

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string RemoveDuplicateChars(
        this string text, Func<string, string> normalizer = null)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        var entropy = new HashSet<string>();
        var iterator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text);

        if (normalizer == null)
        {
            normalizer = x => x.Normalize();
        }

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var character = iterator.GetTextElement();
            if (entropy.Add(normalizer(character)))
            {
                output.Append(character);
            }
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### Unit Tests

Let's test a string that contains variations on the letter `A`, including the Angstrom sign `Å`. The Angstrom sign has unicode codepoint `u212B`, but can also be constructed as the letter `A` with the diacritic `u030A`. Both represent the same character.

```
[TestClass]
public class Fixtures
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Fixture()
    {
        // ÅÅAaA -> ÅAa
        Assert.AreEqual("ÅAa", "\u212BA\u030AAaA"
            .RemoveDuplicateChars());

        // ÅÅAaA -> ÅA
        // Note that the ToLowerInvariant is used to normalize characters
        // when searching for duplicates, it does not mean the output gets
        // transformed to lower case.
        Assert.AreEqual("ÅA", "\u212BA\u030AAaA"
            .RemoveDuplicateChars(x => x.Normalize().ToLowerInvariant()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not much to say other than the usual missing argument null check:

It is valid to write the following:

```
  string test = null;
  test.RemoveDuplicateChars();
```

and `RemoveDuplicateChars` will be called with a `null` for the `this` argument `text`. Therefore you'll have to test for `null`:

```
public static string RemoveDuplicateChars(
    this string text, Func<string, string> normalizer = null)
{
  if (text == null)
    return text;

  ...
```

or throw an exception...

---

The default initialization  of `normalizer` could be a little less verbose:

```
  normalizer = normalizer ?? ((x) => x.Normalize());
```

---

A minor detail: Angstrom and Å: is also represented by `\u00C5`, which your code interprets as equal to Angstrom, but MS Word interprets them as different when using its Find-function?

Comment: Your last point is in particular interesting. Both \u00C5 and \u212B are the Angstrom symbol. The lambda that you rewrote in a more compact way handles _normalisation_. This means that both these characters represent the same glyph. So normalized, they are exactly the same: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.8. I bet MS Word does not normalize, or normalizes using a different algorithm.

Comment: @dfhwze: My point about Angstrom was just to communicate the difference because I observed it - not to tell what is most correct - and I don't think that Word is the most realiable witness of truth :)

Comment: That's the thing, it's hard to tell what is correct, because it depends on the rules to which equivalence is checked. That's why I found your last paragraph spot on. Finding duplicates in Unicode characters is context-bound, maybe even subjective to some point.